# The specified is not in the form required for an e-mail address

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, smtp

@Exception : SystemFormatException: The specified is not in the form required for an e-mail address

this is the code where error occur, please help.

```
Public Sub send_email(ByVal code)`
    Dim tsURL As String = "http://string/server/"
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim email_add As String
    conn1("SELECT * FROM hr_employee WHERE emp_position IN ('QA ENGINEER', 'SR. QA ENGINEER') AND status = 'employed'", "email_add")
    If ds.Tables("email_add").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For n = 0 To ds.Tables("email_add").Rows.Count - 1
            dr = ds.Tables("email_add").Rows(n)
            If n <> ds.Tables("email_add").Rows.Count - 1 Then
                email_add = email_add + dr("email")
                email_add = email_add + ", "
            Else
                email_add = email_add + dr("email")
            End If
        Next
    End If   

 Dim MailFrom1 As String = "e@mail.com"
 Dim MailTo1 As String = email_add
 Dim MailSubject1 As String = "New Carrier Tape : " & code
 Dim MailBody1 As String = vbCrLf & "A new carrier tape (Part Number: " & code & ") has been added into the system. Please verify and buy-off the specs in the MRP system. " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "MRP System: " & tsURL & vbCrLf & "Module: Manufacturing --> First Article --> QA"
Dim MailClient1 = New SmtpClient("localhost")
MailClient1.send(MailFrom1, MailTo1, MailSubject1, MailBody1)
'Catch ex As Exception
'End Try
```

Comment: Presumably it's the contents of `MailTo1` that is the issue.  Have you looked to see exactly what it contains?  If you haven't, why not?  If you have, why haven't you provided it to us?

Comment: Try printing email_add filed, what is value there..!!

Comment: @user2767299 Will try it